# If $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$ exists, does $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$ for $x$ sufficiently large?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to [0,1]$ and assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$ exists.
My question is: can I conclude that for $x$ sufficiently large, $ \lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$ exists as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y)$ exists, then $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y)$ exists, otherwise the first limit is not defined. I think you want $x,y$ to go to infinity at the same time. If this is the case, then it is wrong. A counterexample would be $$ f(x,y)= e^{-x^2} \cos(y)^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I agree. I want to take the limit in $y$ first and then the limit in $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, since you are writing about $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$, you are actually *assuming* that $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$ exists if $x$ is large enough.

Comment: Well, this depends on what definition you use. It's not uncommon to consider it meaningful to study $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ provided only that the domain $D_f$ contains arbitrarily large points. (In other words, it's not required for $f(x)$ to be defined for *all* sufficiently large $x$.) For example, with this convention the definition of the limit of a sequnce, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$, is just a special case of the definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.

Comment: Well in principle I don't think I'm assuming that a priori: I can define $c$ as $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$. Being $c$ a math object, it may exist or not. Now, suppose that an oracle says it exists. If it exists, can I make the desired conclusion?

Comment: @user52227 I didn't just mention it; you stated that it exists.

Comment: @HansLundmark since $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it should be ok

Comment: @user52227: The question is what the domain of the function $g(x)=\lim_{y\to \infty} f(x,y)$ is. If *that* limit fails to exist for some values of $x$, you would say that those $x$ don't belong to $D_g$ and simply disregard them when investing $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ (if you're using the convention that I described above).